# autoscroll is skipping menu items

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3, with the autoscroll plugin. But the autoscroll is skipping over menu items, and selecting the wrong one at the wrong time. i.e. I scroll to section 3 and section 2 is highlighted on the menu.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top alt" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1000">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#sec0">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec1">Gear</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec2">Amenities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec3">Artists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec4">Studios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec5">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sec6">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="header alt vert" id="sec0">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 logo">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo7.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <h4 class="tagline">Dedicated to your sound</h4>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Visit us today!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="sec1" class="blurb">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1>State of the art equipment</h1>
        <p class="lead">At Willow Studios, you will work with only the best gear available.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg blurb-button">View our gear list</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="featurette" id="sec2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>Amazing Amenities</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <img class="img-circle" src="img/Lounge.png">
            <h4>Socialize</h4>
          <p>Kick your feet up in our spacious lounge</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
            <img class="img-circle" src="img/wifi.png">
          <h4>Connect</h4>
          <p>Free Wifi throughout the facilities</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
            <img class="img-circle" src="img/cabin.png">
          <h4>Rest</h4>
          <p>Stay with us at our cabin; accommodates eight</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
            <img class="img-circle" src="img/firepit.png">
          <h4>Warm up</h4>
          <p>Take in some heat by our beautiful fire pit</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec3">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2 class="bg-transparent">Artists / Clients</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
          <div class="row hidden-xs">
               <div class="col-sm-2 bg-transparent spacing-top spacing-bottom">
                   <img class="img-circle grayscale" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5c708a2c9d25d1f2e4195ece1f1c684d?s=80">
                   <p>Recording at Willow Studios was a dream!</p>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2 bg-transparent spacing-top spacing-bottom">
                   <img class="img-circle grayscale" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3bb38f66f79ca138f318af89fe6b02ec?s=80">
                   <p>Recording at Willow Studios was a dream!</p>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2 bg-transparent spacing-top spacing-bottom">
                   <img class="img-circle grayscale" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3423a3e32fda92a5aaed72c7cde3849c?s=80">
                   <p>Recording at Willow Studios was a dream!</p>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-2 bg-transparent spacing-top spacing-bottom">
                   <img class="img-circle grayscale" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/325b6c3c0a75bfdb72822035bb556826?s=80">
                   <p>Recording at Willow Studios was a dream!</p>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a>
               </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 bg-transparent spacing-top spacing-bottom">
                  <img class="img-circle grayscale" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cdd69340b0cfac4c7acb892e3ea7556e?s=80">
                  <p>Recording at Willow Studios was a dream!</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2 bg-transparent spacing-top spacing-bottom">
                  <img class="img-circle grayscale" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/889778901fb1522dac2846ffe62bd960?s=80">
                  <p>Recording at Willow Studios was a dream!</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center spacing-top">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Read all reviews</a>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
... and so on
<ul class="nav pull-right scroll-down">
  <li><a href="#" title="Scroll down"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-3x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav pull-right scroll-top">
  <li><a href="#" title="Scroll to top"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-3x"></i></a>/li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
/* smooth scrolling for scroll to top */
$('.scroll-top').click(function(){
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
})
/* smooth scrolling for scroll down */
$('.scroll-down').click(function(){
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:$(window).scrollTop()+800},1000);
})

/* highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs */
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar' })
```

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you for your time.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LmzTG/

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I captured the scroll event before animating the page, to make sure the menu items were being highlighted at the right time. Also, I added 5 pixels to the incrementation of the scroller, to take into account the header rows between some of my sections. I changed the jQuery code like this:

jQuery:

```
/* highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs */
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar' })

/* smooth scrolling for scroll to top */
$('.scroll-top').click(function(){
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},805);
})
/* smooth scrolling for scroll down */
$('.scroll-down').click(function(){
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:$(window).scrollTop()+805},1000);
})
```

Then, I changed every section's div to be 800 pixels high (to match the increment of the scroller), through its CSS with the height property.

HTML/CSS snipet:

```
<div id="sec1" class="blurb" style="height: 800px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1>State of the art equipment</h1>
        <p class="lead">At Willow Studios, you will work with only the best gear available.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg blurb-button">View our gear list</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="featurette" id="sec2" style="height: 800px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>Amazing Amenities</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <img class="img-circle" src="img/Lounge.png">
            <h4>Socialize</h4>
          <p>Kick your feet up in our spacious lounge</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
            <img class="img-circle" src="img/wifi.png">
          <h4>Connect</h4>
          <p>Free Wifi throughout the facilities</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
            <img class="img-circle" src="img/cabin.png">
          <h4>Rest</h4>
          <p>Stay with us at our cabin; accommodates eight</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
            <img class="img-circle" src="img/firepit.png">
          <h4>Warm up</h4>
          <p>Take in some heat by our beautiful fire pit</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And that was that. It works perfectly well now, although the tradeoff is that accommodating your tallest section leaves some of the sections seeming bare - with little content. So it's a tradeoff: more content, or no autoscroll option for the user.